# 500 in Heroku logs, but no error details from Rails (even with rails_12factor)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

When I tail the logs and hit my app, I have `heroku[router]` telling me I received a 500, and the app shows the usual "We're sorry, but something went wrong" message... but there are no additional details from Rails in the logs to tell me what is causing the 500.

I've read a couple of other threads that asked about this but they mostly end with people suggesting to do a `rake:db migrate` which fixed the error but there's no further discussion about the logging unfortunately. (And yes I'm sure there's no pending migrations )

- I have the rails_12factor gem installed
- I've tried setting `config.log_level = :debug` in `production.rb`
- I've tried creating a config variable of `LOG_LEVEL` set to `DEBUG` (which should supersede the config setting)
- I've set `$stdout.sync = true` in `config.ru` [as suggested here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging)

What am I missing?

As an aside, have tried re-producing my actual problem locally with a backup of the database being used with Heroku but I can't reproduce it, so I'm finally forced to get to the bottom of this logging problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I first just got this to work by manually adding:

`config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`

to production.rb but that obscured the real issue...

`RACK_ENV` and `RAILS_ENV` were both set to `staging` while I had the gem loading in the `:production` set... So although Heroku told me it was using the `rails_12factor` gem when the instance started, it wasn't really (I assumed it wouldn't be listed there if it wasn't a production environment, wrong assumption!)

`staging.rb` was loading `production.rb` which is why setting STDOUT there worked, thus confusing the issue further.

Thanks for the replies, and hope this helps someone else in future - go check your config variables and/or change where the gem is being loaded! :)

Comment: It does. If you bundle list you should see https://github.com/heroku/rails_serve_static_assets make sure it's version 0.0.4. Did you get any warnings in your deploy output?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Schneems! Output of `bundle list` gives ```* rails_12factor (0.0.3)
  * rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.4)
  * rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)``` Build output from Heroku when deploying doesn't have any warnings, and confirms: ```Using rails_12factor 0.0.3 Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4 Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3```

Comment: @jmasson I did set RACK_ENV and RAILS_ENV to production and install rails_12factor but I'm still getting 500 and not the full logs

Answer (score 0):

Debugging errors on heorku can get difficult most of the time.

For people facing a similar problem I suggest using [PaperTrail](https://addons.heroku.com/papertrail) heroku add-on for logging, It is free upto a certain limit.

It is realtime and provides with searching of logs, events hooks, mailing alerts etc. facilities. You will never have trouble debugging errors on heroku.

You can simply install it using the heroku cli command.
    `heroku addons:create papertrail`

Comment: I like Papertrail, and was using it for this app as well, but it's still only getting the logs you're providing it, so still needs the above done.